# Why does graphviz from git not compiled?

Tags: graphviz

I try to build graphviz from git http://github.com/ellson/graphviz/
It stop building with this message

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/peter/work/sdk/graphviz/graphviz-src/graphviz/cmd/gvedit'
  CXX    gvedit-moc_csettings.o
  CXX    gvedit-moc_imageviewer.o
  CXX    gvedit-moc_mainwindow.o
  CXX    gvedit-moc_mdichild.o
  CXX    gvedit-qrc_mdi.o
  CXXLD  gvedit
/usr/bin/ld: gvedit-mainwindow.o: undefined reference to symbol 'agseterrf'
/home/peter/work/sdk/graphviz/graphviz-src/graphviz/lib/cgraph/.libs/libcgraph.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [gvedit] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/peter/work/sdk/graphviz/graphviz-src/graphviz/cmd/gvedit'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Can you point me to the problem?

Comment: I have similar issue:

Comment: ../../lib/cgraph/.libs/libcgraph.so: error: undefined reference to 'aagerror'
../../lib/cgraph/.libs/libcgraph.so: error: undefined reference to 'aaglex'
../../lib/cgraph/.libs/libcgraph.so: error: undefined reference to 'aglexeof'
../../lib/cgraph/.libs/libcgraph.so: error: undefined reference to 'aagin'
../../lib/cgraph/.libs/libcgraph.so: error: undefined reference to 'aglexinit'

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue on the github repo: https://github.com/ellson/graphviz/issues/1

It appears there is some issue with the perl plugin, for me building with

```
    ./configure --enable-perl=no
```

was enough to fix the issue (and I didn't lose any functionality I need).